# How to allow duplicate email/username registrations - Meteor js

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I am working on different domains in a single app... each domain has its own login. for example a  person who has account in domain1 can also register in domain2. I am getting "Email already registered" error..

Comment: There are many ways to do this and it depends on your specific requirements. Either make your own authentication: http://themeteorchef.com/recipes/roll-your-own-authentication/. Or you can use flags to set which domains they've registered in: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_oncreateuser

Comment: @ravi-teja Did you resolved this issues? if you resolved it please share that solution.